# Message must be authenticated error on Sepolia test network

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

When I run this command

```
foundry-simple-storage-f23 % forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol:DeploySimpleStorage --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: 
(code: -32000, message: Must be authenticated!, data: None)
```

I know that it is a problem with the RPC URL but I can't figure out what it is.

I have double checked that the RPC URL I have in my .env file is correct.

I am expecting the code to deploy onto the sepolia test network via alchemy